# Is the following sentence unclear for a native speaker?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"As your company is currently doing, I also believe that now is the perfect time to invest in AR/VR."

What I wanted to express is that I'm currently investing in AR/VR as the company I'm contacting.

Comment: No, it's not unclear, but as a native/near-native speaker, I'd probably say, "Based on your company's current performance, I also believe that now is the perfect time to invest in AR/VR."

Comment: You're comparing *doing* and *believing*, which are not truly suitable comparands.  *I would invest now in X as you are doing* .  **invest** and **doing** are suitable comparands.

Answer (score 2):

It's not great because you're comparing two different things.  "As your company is doing, I believe" - but the company is **doing**, and you're **believing**, so you're not actually doing the same thing.  We would normally say something like "As you do, I also believe..."

Comment: I think you've identified the primary reason why OP's example doesn't come across well. It's secondary that "fronting" the optional comparison clause forces the reader to remember this until he finds out exactly *what* is being compared - which as we can see from other comments/answers causes many people to misunderstand it anyway (they end up assuming ***as*** denotes the sense of ***because***, when it's actually supposed to convey ***in a like manner***).

Answer (score -1):

The beginning of the sentence sounds kind of awkward. I would rewrite it like this:

> Seeing that your company is currently doing very well, I believe that now is the perfect time to invest in AR/VR.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. "Seeing that your company is doing very well" is not exactly what i want to emphasise. My point is more "you are investing in these technologies for the same reasons I am". How would you put it? Now it became more of a discussion between me and my wife, both non-native english speakers. XD

Comment: You think the following sentence would work for you?: As things stand, I believe that now is the perfect time to invest in AR/VR.

Comment: @Rollo - Yes, you can start a sentence with _"as your company is.."_, Why not? However, it might be improved in order to sound like a native.

Comment: But can you put in the same sentence these concepts or is too complex for the way english people write?
* Like your company, I'm also investing in VR because I believe that now is the perfect time to do so.

Comment: @Rollo - Your sentence sounds fine to me, but you can do some improvement in order to make it more "fluent" - _Considering the company's current perfomance, I presume it's now the perfect time to invest in AR/VR._

Comment: -1 - Per [my comment to the correct" answer above](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/is-the-following-sentence-unclear-for-a-native-speaker#comment260751_115024), you're misparsing ***as*** there.